# Integrating a print-icon and date-picker into ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net

I'm following an online tutorial to add in [functional print-icon and javascript date-picker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504567/Print-button-Date-picker-in-SSRS-Reports-for-Non-I).  But I'm having trouble incorporating it into my existing .ASPX project.

It tells me to first, put a  "server side iframe below the report viewer".

```
   <iframe id="frmPrint" name="frmPrint" runat="server" style = "display:none"></iframe>
```

Then,  it says to put the "following div tag below the iframe declaration(This is to display the message while processing the ajax request of printing)."

```
    <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
    <table align="center" valign="middle" style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <tr>
    <td><img id="img-spinner" src="App_Data/print_icon.png" alt="Printing"/></td>
    <td><span style="font-family:Verdana; font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;width:86px;">Printing...</span></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

So supposing I'm making a default web-site, where does that go in the "Default.aspx" page? I'm a bit lost , any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the default pages in VS2012 are different than VS2010, but I've just got 2010 on here.

Just blank out the default stuff they generate and replace with your example code. It should end up looking like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1"  EnablePageMethods="true" 
    EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>     

    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvREXReport" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="798px"
Style="display: table !important; margin: 0px; overflow: auto !important;" 
ShowBackButton="true" onreportrefresh="rrvREXReport_ReportRefresh">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>   

 <iframe id="frmPrint" name="frmPrint" runat="server" style = "display:none"></iframe> 

<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
<table align="center" valign="middle" style="height:100%;width:100%">
<tr>
<td><img id="img-spinner" src="../Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Printing"/></td>
<td><span style="font-family:Verdana; font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;width:86px;">Printing...</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks,so i'm a little confused at what's going on here  . does the datepicker get put in a div ?  also, what is `onreportrefresh="rrvREXReport_ReportRefresh"`

Comment: The author of the codeProject article is doing something a little sneaky to get that date picker. From what I understand you'll need to run the example and look at the generated HTML to get an ID value. Looking at the showDatePicker() javascript function it looks like you might want the ID of a table row? I didn't run the code to see for sure.

Comment: Ah, OK - I'll have a coffe and focus then :)

Comment: onreportrefresh is an event handler you set in the codebehind. See Viewer.aspx.cs line 87